# Java List type parameter

Tags: java, list, methods

I have a method which looks like this

```
public void setDayIntervals(Days day, List<HourRange> ranges) {
        int hourMask = 0;
        for (HourRange intRange : ranges) {
                     int Start= intRange.getStart();
                     int end = intRange.getEnd();
            }
        }

}
```

I have to pass List of Ranges from another class.

```
for(int s = 0; s < adSchedule.getTargets().length ; s++ ){
        List<HourRange> ranges = null;
        int Start =  adSchedule.getTargets(s).getStartHour();
        int end =  adSchedule.getTargets(s).getEndHour()-1;
            if(adSchedule.getTargets(s).getDayOfWeek()==DayOfWeek.MONDAY ){
               // ranges ????????? here i have to pass values Start and End 
               CamSchedule.setDayIntervals(Days.ONE, ranges);
             }
    }
```

Can someone tell me how to pass ranges in the above method `setDayIntervals(Days.one, ramges)`

```
public static class HourRange {
        int start;
        int end;

        public HourRange(int start, int end) {
            super();
            if(start > end) 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        public int getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        public int getEnd() {
            return end;
        }
}
```

Comment: What does the constructor for the HourRange class look like?

Comment: Is this homework or are you maintaining someone else's code?

Comment: for `HourRange`: you don't need to call `super()` because `HourRange` extends nothing but `Object`. And you could add `private` modifiers to `start` and `end` to make the class immutable (unless someone uses dirty tricks like reflection..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an `HourRange` object and add it to the list. Something like this:

```
 ranges.add(new HourRange(Start, end));
```

<strike>The example assumes that `HourRange` has this constructor:</strike>

```
 public HourRange(int start, int end) {
   // code to copy start and end to internal fields.
 }
```

<sup>(it **has** this constructor)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`List<HourRange> ranges = null;`

you probably want

`List<HourRange> ranges = new ArrayList<HourRange>();`

That gives you a list to add to; until you initialize ranges as a list, nothing can go into that list.

Comment: Or in this case, just `Collections.singletonList<HourRange>(new HourRange...`